# msvc std::chrono::time_zone::get_info throws an exception saying: The operation completed successfully

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-chrono

I was trying to convert utc time returned from `std::chrono::system_clock` to local time before displaying it using `std::format` but I got a surprising exception from `std::chrono::time_zone::to_local` and its what message says: `The operation completed successfully.` What a surprise ! I looked into this method and it called `std::chrono::time_zone::get_info` on the passed time parameter and did a simple conversion so I tested `std::chrono::time_zone::get_info` separately and it was the source of this exception. I don't know is it a bug in the implementation or my code is buggy ?

Here is a simple code which throws this error:

```
            try
            {
                const std::chrono::time_zone* current_z = std::chrono::current_zone();
                std::cout << "current timezone name: " << current_z->name() << "\n";
                auto sys_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
                std::cout << "current system time: " << sys_time << "\n";
                auto sys_info = current_z->get_info(sys_time); // throws exception what(): The operation completed successfully.
                std::cout << "sys_info: offset: " << sys_info.offset << ", abbrev" << sys_info.abbrev << "\n";
                //auto local_time = current_z->to_local(sys_time); // throws exception since it calls get_info
                //std::cout << "current local time: " << local_time << "\n";
            }
            catch (const std::exception& ex)
            {
                std::cout << "caught exception: " << ex.what();
            }
```

EDIT: After looking at `std::chrono::time_zone::get_info` source code it will invoke this method: `std::chrono::time_zone::_Get_info` and its source

```
        template <class _Duration>
        _NODISCARD sys_info _Get_info(const _Duration& _Dur) const {
            using _Internal_duration = duration<__std_tzdb_epoch_milli, milli>;
            const auto _Internal_dur = _CHRONO duration_cast<_Internal_duration>(_Dur);
            const unique_ptr<__std_tzdb_sys_info, _Tzdb_deleter<__std_tzdb_sys_info>> _Info{
                __std_tzdb_get_sys_info(_Name.c_str(), _Name.length(), _Internal_dur.count())};
            if (_Info == nullptr) {
                _Xbad_alloc();
            } else if (_Info->_Err == __std_tzdb_error::_Win_error) {
                _XGetLastError();
            } else if (_Info->_Err == __std_tzdb_error::_Icu_error) {
                _Xruntime_error("Internal error loading IANA database information");
            }

            constexpr auto _Min_internal =
                _CHRONO duration_cast<_Internal_duration>(_Min_seconds.time_since_epoch()).count();
            constexpr auto _Max_internal =
                _CHRONO duration_cast<_Internal_duration>(_Max_seconds.time_since_epoch()).count();
            const auto _Begin =
                _Info->_Begin <= _Min_internal
                    ? _Min_seconds
                    : sys_seconds{_CHRONO duration_cast<sys_seconds::duration>(_Internal_duration{_Info->_Begin})};
            const auto _End =
                _Info->_End >= _Max_internal
                    ? _Max_seconds
                    : sys_seconds{_CHRONO duration_cast<sys_seconds::duration>(_Internal_duration{_Info->_End})};
            return {.begin = _Begin,
                .end       = _End,
                .offset    = _CHRONO duration_cast<seconds>(_Internal_duration{_Info->_Offset}),
                .save      = _CHRONO duration_cast<minutes>(_Internal_duration{_Info->_Save}),
                .abbrev    = _Info->_Abbrev};
        }
```

the `_Info` pointer returned by `__std_tzdb_get_sys_info` is not `nullptr` but its `_Err` is set to 1 which equals `__std_tzdb_error::_Win_error` so `_XGetLastError` is called to throw an exception with the error code from `GetLastError` and it will return 0 indicating no error code so an exception is thrown indicating that no error has happened ! seems a bug in microsoft stl code

Comment: Fwiw, your code looks fine to me.

Comment: it was a bug in stl that is now partially solved. https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/3097

Answer (score 1):

Per
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/time-zone-class?view=msvc-170

Looks like you should first use get_tzdb() as in

```
const auto& timeZoneDatabase = get_tzdb(); // initialize the time zone database
const auto& currentZone = timeZoneDatabase.current_zone();
```

Comment: it was a bug in stl that is now partially solved. https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/3097

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses a timezone "short name" internally.
The short name of "America/New_York" timezone is for exemple "UTF−5".
But between "UTF" and "5", it's not a "-" but a "−" (U+2212)

The wide to narrow string conversion may fail depending on your local code page.

I solve the problem forcing the application code page to UTF-8.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, ".utf8");
```

Hope this will help.